# how to set cookie in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i tried following code for set cookie but i can't get the cookie.

```
if($this->input->post('remember')){                    
                $this->load->helper('cookie');
                $cookie = array(
                        'name'   => 'remember_me',
                        'value'  => 'test',                            
                        'expire' => '300',                                                                                   
                        'secure' => TRUE
                        );
               set_cookie($cookie);                   
   }
```

and following code is for get cookie

```
$cookie= get_cookie('remember_me');  
 var_dump($cookie);
```

can any one tell me what's the problem is there?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check CodeIgniter cookie helper, it's very simple: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: have you load the helper as:  **`$this->load->helper('cookie');`**  if not do it.. and also instead of **`set_cookie($cookie);`** use` $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);`

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

instead of set_cookie($cookie);

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a controller class and add the following code to it;

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Stop Its demostrate how to set cookie');

class cw_cookies extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()

   {

       parent::__construct();

       $this->load->helper('cookie');

   }



   function set()

   {

       $cookie= array(

           'name'   => 'remember_me',
           'value'  => 'test',                            
           'expire' => '300',                                                                                   
           'secure' => TRUE

       );

       $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

       echo "Congratulation Cookie Set";

   }



   function get()

   {

       echo $this->input->cookie('remember_me',true);

   }

}
```

The above code sets the cookies through

```
$this->input->set_cookie()
```

The helper is loaded using:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

You can read more at : [Set Cookies in Codeigniter](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/set-cookies-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Perfect! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function cookie()
    {
        $this->load->helper('cookie');

        $name   = 'user';
        $value  = 'pradip';
        $expire = time()+1000;
        $path  = '/';
        $secure = TRUE;

        setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$path); 

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
```

Call in view page like `echo $this->input->cookie('user');`

> output = pradip

Answer (score 1):

Say data

```
$my_cookie= array(

       'name'   => 'remember_me',
       'value'  => 'test value',                            
       'expire' => '3000',                                                                                   
       'secure' => TRUE

   );
```

Use

```
$this->input->set_cookie($my_cookie);
```

instead of

```
set_cookie($my_cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

first add this line to the top of your controller

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('cookie', 'url'));
}
```

and then set cookie as

```
set_cookie('counters','ok','999600');
```