# how to keep user logged in even when browser is closed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, session, basic-authentication

I have this problem in my login system that after login if user closes the window/browser and then open that same page it will ask to login again. I want to keep user logged in until user logs out. 
I am using following code to login user

```
  public function adminLogin()
   {
   $email = $this->input->post('email');
   $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
   $user = $this->login_model->getUserDate($email,$password);
   $user_data = array(
              'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
              'role' => $user['role'],
              'logged_in' => true
              );
   $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
   redirect('admin-panel');
 }
```

and this is config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 172800;//48 hours
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

How can i achieve this, so that user doesn't have to login again when window/browser is closed and reopened.

Comment: you can achieve this by using `cookies`

Comment: how can i do this with cookies, can you guide?

Comment: You need to read userdata from the session and consider the user logged in when the userdata has logged_in true.

Comment: to be more precise you could store your logged in variables into a cookie(s) then have a script that checks for the cookie(s) to see if there is a username /role assign those and update the cookie and if it doesn't exists, then have it proceed to the login screen.

Comment: The session already has a cookie defined.

Comment: I got the issye solved i was misssing to check if logged_in is true

Comment: @Danimal comment is accurate. Here is how to set a cookie in `CI`- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132448/how-to-set-cookie-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use cookies with timer.

```
<?php
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

[Check this source](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)